# How to solve an eigensystem faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I have a module that I need to call 1-10 million times in my program. Currently, it is taking several hours to run so I am hoping that I can cut down some runtime with your help.

```
r = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0., 1./2.], 6];

es = Eigensystem[H0[ω0, r[[1]], r[[2]], r[[3]], r[[4]], r[[5]], r[[6]] ];

ε = es[[1]];
v = es[[2]];
vS = Conjugate[v];

(*elements of v and vS are called later; v[[1]], vS[[1]] etc...*)
```

H0 is a compiled function which sped things up a little. 
It looks like this:

[image].

In copy-paste form,

```
 H0={{0, (ωz1 - ωz2)/
 2, (-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy1)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]), (ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (
 I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(
 2 Sqrt[2])}, {(ωz1 - ωz2)/2, 
 0, (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy1)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (
 I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(
 2 Sqrt[2])}, {(-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (
 I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (
 I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]), ω0 + (ωz1 + ωz2)/2, 
0}, {(ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy1)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(
 2 Sqrt[2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (
 I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[2]), 
0, -ω0 + 1/2 (-ωz1 - ωz2)}}
```

Is there anything else that can be optimized here?

Comment: Without you saying more on `H0[]`, there's really nothing else to say, except that the computation of an eigensystem can be simplified a bit, if the matrix given to it has some structure (e.g. symmetry, sparseness).

Comment: Just to check - is whatever loop you have running 10 mil times parallellized?

Comment: @J. M. H0[] is 4x4 Hermitian. Four elements of the matrix are 0.

Comment: VF1 Well, the loop runs millions of times because I'm doing an average. I run the loop for several different parameters. I use ParallelTable for the computation of the loop for each of the parameters. The actual loop (e.g. Sum) is not in parallel though. It's a choice between using ParallelSum or ParallelTable. Though I'm not sure which one will be faster in this particular case, in prior instances ParallelTable has done a better job for me.

Comment: "Four elements of the matrix are 0." - which ones? You'll have to be more explicit than that for answerers to get anywhere...

Comment: J. M. I have added an image of the matrix.

Comment: @BeauGeste Are you calculating the eigensystem for each choice of random parameters (rather than doing it once symbolically and then substitute specific values) ?

Comment: Exactly! Solve the system symbolically (if possible), compile the resulting equations and this will be as quick as possible. Include copy-pastable code of the matrix will perhaps prompt somebody to post this as an answer.

Comment: b.gatessucks Ajasja I have not been doing it symbolically. The eigenvectors are huge. Plus they need to be normalized which makes the expressions even larger.

Comment: I compared using symbolic compiled eigenvectors (non-normalized) versus the numerical approach. The numerical approach was identical or slightly faster.

Comment: The title of this question is not really helpful. Would you mind choosing a more informative one (e.g. mentioning eigensystems) now the problem is clearer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is too long for a comment and honestly, to give a real answer, there is more information required in your question. Isn't it possible, that you give a working example, so that we see what takes long and how you implemented it?

If you are calling `Eigensystem` for many different input values which are know, there is still some place for speed-up. Since your expressions are very lengthy, please find the initialization in an extra section.

First we measure how long it takes to calculate the Eigenvectors of `H0` for 1 Million random values

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000000, 7}];
First@AbsoluteTiming[Eigenvectors[H0[#]] & /@ data]
```

This took **44.4 sec** here.
The next thing you can try is to distribute `H0` over parallel kernels and use `ParallelMap`

```
DistributeDefinitions[H0];
First@AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMap[Eigenvectors[H0[#]] &, data]]
```

This took **25.3 sec** with 4 subkernels. Let's test the compiled code. First when we apply it non-parallel

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[evectors @@@ data]
```

This took **2.4 sec** which is almost 20 times faster then the initial version. Let's see what we can get if we call it parallel

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[evectors @@ Transpose[data]]
```

This took only **0.24 sec**. If this scales well, that it means I can run 10 million samples in about 2.5 seconds. An indeed, a test with $10^7$ runs required **2.75 sec**.

Now you might ask, ***whaat??***, why is `evectors @@@ data` a serial call while `evectors @@ Transpose[data]` is parallel? It's because of the `Listable` attribute in the `Compile`-call and since we turn on `Parallelization`. Sure is

```
evectors @@@ data == evectors @@ Transpose[data]

(* Out[21]= True *)
```

### Initialization

Compiled parallel "C" versions of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

```
{evalues, evectors} = 
  Compile[{{ω0, _Complex, 0}, {ωx1, _Complex, 
       0}, {ωx2, _Complex, 0}, {ωy1, _Complex, 
       0}, {ωy2, _Complex, 0}, {ωz1, _Complex, 
       0}, {ωz2, _Complex, 0}}, #, Parallelization -> True, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] & /@ 
   Eigensystem[{{0, (ωz1 - ωz2)/
       2, (-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]), (ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2])}, {(ωz1 - ωz2)/2, 
      0, (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2])}, {(-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]), ω0 + (ωz1 + ωz2)/2, 
      0}, {(ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
           2]), 0, -ω0 + 1/2 (-ωz1 - ωz2)}}];
```

Furthermore, I try to copy your approach by defining `H0`

```
H0[{ω0_, ωx1_, ωx2_, ωy1_, ωy2_, 
ωz1_, ωz2_}] = 
  N[{{0, (ωz1 - ωz2)/
      2, (-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]), (ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2])}, {(ωz1 - ωz2)/2, 
     0, (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2])}, {(-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]), ω0 + (ωz1 + ωz2)/2, 
     0}, {(ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
          2]), 0, -ω0 + 1/2 (-ωz1 - ωz2)}}];
```

Comment: thanks for you analysis. The times look very promising. I need the eigenvectors to be normalized. Is it possible to get normalized vectors out of Eigensystem?

Comment: @Beau, look up `Normalize[]` and `Orthogonalize[]`.

Comment: @halirutan This code is still of great help to me(for fast processing). _Just one query(which will solve my problem of asking similar question in MMSE), in intialization_ `{evalues, evectors}`, _you wrote whole matrix again inside_ `Eigensystem`, **is it required**. As in my case, matrix is insanely large and its size changes(by changing size parameter), do I need to copy my matrix again. Error I am getting`o,compiledFunction1,{{Real,0,Constant},{Real,0,Constant},{Real,0,\
Constant}},Real]]] are not the same shape`

Comment: The main reason for the speed up here is that the OP wanted eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the same matrix for different matrix elements. So we calculated the `Eigensystem` only one time and built a compiled function from it. When your matrix changes on each call, this method won't work for you. Do you call `{evalues, evectors}` for a specific matrix several times or only exactly once?

Comment: @halirutan Thanks. I am calling for particular size only once. Ex: If I have a 11X11 then I am only evaluating(evectors and evalues) for that size once. Storing them inside some matrix, to say. Will this work?

Comment: @halirutan In initialization does it matter for `{evalues, evectors}` to be written as `{evalues, evectors}:=`(set delayed) instead of `{evalues, evectors}=`? In my case using first I am getting result(with an error) but using second it shows running(longer than the time it takes for  former intialization). _Your help will be of great use to me(I am really stuck, trying from past two days)_. Thanks

Comment: If you only calculate each matrix once, then don't compile it. It will slow down everything. Just use `Eigensystem` to calculate what you need.

Comment: @halirutan I am seeing your helpful replies very late(as you didn't add @L.K., in the comments). This will be last nudge, as here after initialization you have added different ways(differing by time consumption). I only need to care about the fastest one, so after initialization I can copy `evectors @@ Transpose[data]`. Forgive me for asking obvious things.

Comment: @L.K. Why don't you stick around in the [chat] for a while? I'm usually online there and we can discuss where exactly you have problems. The other choice is to ask a separate question with a small example pointing out how your situation is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52786/discussion-between-l-k-and-halirutan).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider simplifying your matrix by substituting the [Omega] pairs that occur often with a dummy.  This will simplify your matrix  as there are only very few variables left. All you need to do is design a pattern to replace the most common [Omega] pairs (in that order). After the Eigensystem calculation, you can substitute them back.

I did something similar where several component were frequently occuring however were nested in divisions on several levels. Standard Simplify did not work, so I wrote my own which substantially increased performance of the simplified matrix.

The pattern I used was the simple
     Power[x_,y__]
How you identify what combination to substitute depends on what's underlying your system, I am not really up to speed on Fourier transformations but this seems to be underlying what you are analysing here.

Below example gives your a transformastionRules fir the matrix and a reverseTransformation after the Eigensystem is calculated.

```
dummycount=1;
Position[HO,(*pattern*)];
H0[[#/.List->Sequence]]&/@Position[H0,(*pattern*)];
Sort[Cases[Tally[%],Except[{_,1}]],#1[[2]]>#2[[2]]&];
transformationRules=Rule[#[[1]],dummy[dummycount++]]&/@%;
reverseTransformation=transformationRules/.Rule[x_,y_]->Rule[y,x];
```

@halirutan : Thanks for the excellent example, I achieved several orders of magnitude speed-up for a program I was working on; however when I tested the execution of the compiled code without CompilationTarget->"C" something changes:

```
evectors@@@data==Eigenvectors[H0[#]]&/@data
(* False *)
Eigenvectors[H0[#]]&/@data==ParallelMap[Eigenvectors[H0[#]]&,data]
(* True *)
ParallelMap[Eigenvectors[H0[#]]&,data]==evectors@@Transpose[data]
(* False *)
evectors@@@data==evectors@@Transpose[data]
(* True *)
```

It seems to me the compiled functions behave differently from the non-compiled but I cannot discover where the difference is. I did create a trivial (2 dimension) example which simply swapped output and hence was easily corrected by

```
Reverse/@(evectors@@Transpose[data])
```

but for higher dimensions it is unclear what causes it to change its output.

Also, removing the 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable} 
attribute did not change anything. The problem seems to be that parameters are passed on to EigenSystem in listable manner and Eigensystem seems not to work in Listable mode;
    Eigensystem::matsq :  "Argument {…} is not a non-empty square matrix.

However rewriting the code in what I believe to be functional identical by:

```
cpfnc = Compile[{{ω0,ωx1,ωx2,ωy1,ωy2,ωz1,ωz2},
Module[{eval,evec},{eval,evec} = Eigensystem[{{0, (ωz1 - ωz2)/
   2, (-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]), (ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2])}, {(ωz1 - ωz2)/2, 
  0, (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2])}, {(-ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) - (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]), ω0 + (ωz1 + ωz2)/2, 
  0}, {(ωx1 - ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) - (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]), (ωx1 + ωx2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]) + (I ωy1)/(2 Sqrt[2]) + (I ωy2)/(2 Sqrt[
       2]), 0, -ω0 + 1/2 (-ωz1 - ωz2)}}];
{eval,evec}],
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}],Parallelization -> True];
```

does give the correct output, however again Listable provides problems for EigenSystem[] once parallel input is provided.

Love to have your views!

Comment: I can't test this in version 7, but the difference in behavior that you observe may be caused by `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`.  Have you considered that?

Comment: You are right, The parameters are passed on, assuming EigenSystem has attribute Listable. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `Length[r]==6` the following will be faster.

```
es = Apply[Eigensystem[H0[\[Omega]0,##]]&,r];
```

Well I may not have the syntax right because I am doing this with my iPhone. My point is use one call to Apply instead of six calls to Part.

If `Length[r]>6`, then change `##` to (#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6).