# Diagonalization in parallel

Tags: linear-algebra, parallelization, high-performance-clusters

I would like to diagonalize one unitary non-sparse matrix of size 12870 with complex number entries (not symbols, this is really a numerical problem). Is it possible to make eigensystem run in parallel - I have access to an HPC cluster with many kernels - so that the diagonalization runs as fast as possible?

Comment: Likely the best approach to this problem is to use/write a parallel solver in your favorite traditional language and call it from mathematica.

Comment: I guess it can help you: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13419/how-to-solve-an-eigensystem-faster

Comment: Have you tried it? `Eigenvalues` for instance should use all available cores on the machine it's running. By the way 12870 is `Binomial[16, 8]` so presumably you're looking at spinless fermions on a 16-site lattice at half filling? And the entries are complex so you are looking at a time-dependent H? Or maybe a density matrix? (idle guessing here while waiting for mma to finish something)

Comment: @acl . You are close! Eigenvalues uses all the cores (there are 12 nodes) but still takes 2 hours. I need to do this for 500 matrices of the same size.

Comment: Could you not run the same calculation in independent subkernels, using eg `ParallelTable`? That's what I do. Also, useful options might include `SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 8];` and
`SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 8];`. If these suggestions don't help, could you explain why so we can come up with something?

Comment: How do you decide the number - in your example you chose 8 - to put?

Comment: @lagoa In this particular case I just randomly put something to paste it here. For me it's useful so I can prevent Mathematica from taking all available CPUs when I run stuff on our cluster at work (which annoys our sysadmins and my colleagues).

Comment: It seems that by default `MKLThreads` is set to the number of cores the CPU of the current machine has. Did you check how many cores Mathematica uses when you try to diagonalize your matrix?

Comment: For a dense numerical problem, that you want to distribute over a cluster--provided that it can be done at machine precision, my suggestion would be to use ScaLAPACK (but make sure that your cluster has InfiniBand). But I think that @acl's suggestion of doing the 500 matrices in parallel one on each node, rather than one at a time over all nodes, will be more computationally efficient.